# DBT seed send an error "In adapter.dispatch, got a string packages argument ("dbt_utils"), but packages should be None or a list."

Tags: python, sql, dbt

I met an error when run "dbt seed" but don't know how to fix it. I searched this error but no one have it. Can someone help me how to fix this error?

```
**Encountered an error:
Compilation Error in model combined_bookings (models/example/transform/combined_bookings.sql)
  In adapter.dispatch, got a string packages argument ("dbt_utils"), but packages should be None or a list.
  
  > in macro union_relations (macros/sql/union.sql)
  > called by model combined_bookings (models/example/transform/combined_bookings.sql)**
```

This is combined_bookings.sql

```
{{ dbt_utils.union_relations(
        relations=[ref('bookings_1'), ref('bookings_2')]
) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your installed versions of dbt and the dbt_utils package are incompatible. The output of `dbt debug` would tell you that, but you may have to check your `packages.yml` file to be sure. It's highly recommended to always pin your package versions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank for your information. I installed the newest version of dbt and it ran without error.